# Number of tests to perform to get confidence rate

Tags: probability

If I have an issue that causes a failure at a rate of, say, 1 in 20 cycles and then deploy a fix, how do I work out how many test cycles to perform to be confident to 95% that the fix worked?

I know this is possibly straightforward but I can't find the right thing when searching!

Edit: Trying to re-phrase and add more detail.

Assume that the fix is supposed to be a full fix (i.e. stop the issue occurring again). I am trying to work out how many cycles to perform without a failure to be, say, 95% certain that the issue is fixed and not just that it is not seen as I did not run enough cycles.

Comment: First of all we need to define "fixed", is fixed a 1/50 rate for example? 1/100? In any case, a proper answer would probably employ Zhu (2016) [Sample Size Calculation for Comparing Two Poisson or Negative Binomial Rates in Noninferiority or Equivalence Trials](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/19466315.2016.1225594). That said, if we are willing to assume that we care for a difference in binomial proportions, we can do a standard proportions power calculations like: `power.prop.test( p1= 1/20, p2 = 1/50, power = 0.90, alternative = "one")`; in that sense about 650 samples suffice.

Comment: The failure rate is 1/20 before fix. If the failure rate is 1/10 after fix, your confidence will decrease as the number of test cycles increases. So your question has no answer, because you did not provide enough information.

Comment: @user158565: 1/20 < 1/10, so if anything the fix is detrimental in that case. (But yeah, we need a bit more info.) :)

Answer (score 0):

Provided your test cycles are independent trials, this looks like a typical case for a binomial confidence interval.

There is no minimum number of test cycles for a 95% confidence interval (other than that it has to be positive), but the more you do the smaller your confidence interval will be. If you use a large number of trials you can use the normal approximation.

$CI=\hat{p} \pm z \sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n}}$

where $\hat{p}$ is the estimated failure rate, and $z$ is the number corresponding to a 95% range of the standard normal distribution (i.e. 1.96), and $n$ is the number of test cycles. As you can see, $n$  only serves to shrink your interval size, and of course it is part of your estimate for $\hat{p}$.

The normal approximation can be used for large sample sizes, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) offers several other possibilities.

Comment: I think this is what I am after. Let me give more background: I have previously seen, in a software issue tracking system, where you log how often an issue occurred (e.g. 1 in 20 tests) and then the system gives the number of cycles to use in validation to get confidence to 90%, 95%, 99%. I am trying to figure out how that is calculated. Is that what your answer does (re-arranging for n, but then what is CI)?

Comment: CI are the boundaries for the confidence interval (note the $\pm$ in the formula, so it's really two values). Given a certain absolute width around $\hat{p}$, one could set the substraction of those two boundaries equal to that absolute width, rearrange and solve for $n$. For example, if I want my 95% interval to be 2 percent points wide, I'd set the difference in the boundaries to 0.02, and then solve. Note that $z$ varies for different confidence intervals (it's only 1.96 for the 95%, for 90% it's 1.65)